selective use of a pseudoclass
I am using a pseudo-class to change the bullets of all unordered li elements by default to 4 boxes and a white right pointing arrow (▢▢▢▢▷):
      li:before {
        content: "\25A2\25A2\25A2\25A2\25B7";
        padding-right: 0;
      }

I would like to add another pseudo-class to change certain lis to have the same 4 boxes but a black right pointing arrow (▢▢▢▢▶):
      .known li:before {
        content: "\25A2\25A2\25A2\25A2\25B6";
        padding-right: 0;
      }

<li>general data</li>               <-default for most
<li class="known">marked data</li>  <-those few select cases

Apparently this method (using a class selector) doesn't work with pseudo-classes.
I am fairly new to pseudo-classes, as I just learned to use them to change all bullets to something else but don't know how to conditionally apply them (like using a class).
As it stands now, I would have to change content to '' and manually add the boxes and arrow types to each li element's data.

What's the HTML to it? tried li.known::before { ... } already?

prior to this I had '.known' before the 'li' (.known li::before). Using 'li.known::before' works as I want it. Thank you.

Your CSS selector is wrong. It queries for list items inside an element having class known, which doesn't match your markup. This is not an issue with pseudo-selectors.

You have to use li.known::before as a selector:


li::before {
  content: "\25A2\25A2\25A2\25A2\25B7";
  padding-right: 0;
}
 
li.known::before {
  content: "\25A2\25A2\25A2\25A2\25B6";
  padding-right: 0;
}
<li>general data</li>
<li class="known">marked data</li>



.known li::before looks for li that are child elements of an element with the class: known. A space between selectors means that the following must be a descendant (not a direct one).

Simple and to the point, thank you. This also showed me that positioning of a class selector can be important.

You can use following code, to select list items with the .known class:
li.known:before {
  content: "\25A2\25A2\25A2\25A2\25B6";
  padding-right: 0;
}

Using .know li:before would access all <li>-elements inside of all .known-elements.
Using the upper approach, you are selecting all <li>-elements with the .known class.
